# Android debug without USB

Tags: android, android-logcat

I use Eclipse and I want to debug my app using my device but without damaging its battery, because I should always charge it when it's still not discharged. Is it possible to connect a device to adb without connecting it via USB?
I tried with logcat apps but it's a bit uncomfortable. I searched an app that doesn't require root and records the log but I didn't found it.

Comment: Without draining its battery? My devices *charge* the battery when I hook them into USB. I'm not clear on what you're asking.

Comment: Debugging shouldn't stop your device charging once connected via USB. You could just copy the apk over and install it on the phone while it is charging I guess and test it that way, run a logcat application. I've tried the USB debugging on HTC Desire, Desire X, HTC One, LG Nexus 4 and Samsung Galaxy S4 and ALL charge while connected to USB even if debugging... What device are you on?

Comment: @Geobits sorry I corrected my question.

Comment: @RossC I have a Galaxy S3

Comment: @UmbySlipKnot should be the same...? Why can't you use USB and let it charge while debugging, one of the guys here is doing it on the desk beside me...? I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: @RossC the problem is that charging the battery when it's still not discharged can damage the battery in the long run, isn't it?

Comment: @UmbySlipKnot the battery manufacturers say on their own equipment the charge from 40% to 80% then unplug. It won't wreck your battery.

Comment: I don't think, he is asking about charging and draining the battery. His question was "it is possible to debug the application without using  USB cable?" So I found some app by which we can see the Log files like Log viewer.  I found the other app by which we can debug via bluetooth and wifi, but most of this app will only work if device is rooted.

Answer (score 14):

There are a couple ways to debug without ADB(with root):

- Use a logcat application from the store
- Use a [WiFi ADB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en) app

If you're using Jelly Bean or newer, you won't be able to use the logcat apps without root. No matter *which* version you're running, the wifi method requires root.

Basically, if you don't have root, you might want to stick with a good old fashioned USB cable.

Comment: I'm runnign a Logcat App on 4.2.2 without root..?

Comment: [That shouldn't work any more.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/6U4A5irWang) At least not for third-party logs. The app will work, you just won't see everything.

Comment: @RossC not one that gives you actual logs from your or other apps. you only get dalvik logs on 4.1 and up

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the wifi adb app. My phone has a damaged USB port and can't be used to debug with eclipse so that is a big help.

Answer (score -2):

No in order to debug using your device you must connect using a USB.

When plugging in with a USB it will charge your device however I find that using my daytime phone for testing it will cause future problems with the battery due to over charging.

In 3 years I have never come across away that would allow you to debug without connecting the device with a USB.

If someone knows of a method though I would love to know.

Comment: Install app, plug into charger and run a LogCat program from the Play Store (eg aLogCat) or such. I GUESS you could do it that way but it seems a bit mad imho.

Comment: You got an unlucky avatar there, chap.

Comment: @EfEsm I never even realised!!!

Comment: @jonhopkins well I am pleased to know that it means that. Thank you! Wouldn't have wanted it to offend anyone

Comment: @RossC I know this method but it's a bit uncomfortable. I searched an app that don't require root and records the log but I didn't found it.

Comment: @UmbySlipKnot In JB they changed the logcat permissions, so you *can't* read other apps' logs without root. You won't find one that does if you're on JB.