# Debugging apps in Android Studio without using a USB cable at all?

Tags: android-studio

For some reason I am unable to connect my Android phone to PC using a USB cable. I have tried everything from changing cable, updating drivers and even factory resetting the phone but nothing works. Consequently I can not debug in Android Studio. Is there any way to debug(using Bluetooth, WiFi or something else) without using a USB cable at all?

PS: Please do not mark this question as duplicate. I have already read answer to similar questions([one of them is this])[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117359/android-debug-without-usb) but the solution suggested there involves using USB cable at least once(for initial setting of debugging via Bluetooth/WiFi). Is there any way that let you debug apps without using a USB cable at all?

Comment: To confirm, you already enabled USB Debugging under Developer options?

Comment: @Geremy Yes I did.

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: And which Android version?

Comment: I am using Windows and Android Lollipop.

Comment: What happens when you connect the cable to the computer and Android, and type adb logcat at the windows command prompt?  Be sure the Android phone is unlocked when you do this.

Comment: It displays
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
- waiting for device -

Comment: and then it keeps running in that state.

Comment: Ok, this is the basic place to begin your troubleshooting from.  If you cannot get output here, you will not be able to get connectivity from a development perspective anywhere else.